# How can I display the root category in the categories bradcrumbs on Prestashop 1.7.8?

Tags: symfony, smarty, prestashop-1.7, breadcrumbs

As per question's title I am trying to display the root category in categories breadcrumbs.
I can do this easily by adding some code to the breadcrumbs' function in the category controller or a even a module by overriding the above function but I would like to know if this is possible through my custom theme using smarty code.

In the controller file I use:

```
'url'   => $this->context->link->getCategoryLink(Category::getRootCategory()->id, $rootCategory->link_rewrite)
```

inside the breadcrumb links array and it works fine but my concern here is that i modify the core code and i will lose my changes on upcoming Prestashop updates.

Comment: Are you working on a module or changing the template directly? Did you try to check all the smarty vars available? Probably there is already that info.

Comment: I am building my own theme.